# Problems with inline CSS in Tiny MCE-Editor in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

So I made this Joomla website. Works great and all. However there are some issues while editing posts.

The thing is, that the editor allows [inline css styles in the html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp). I want the template of my website to do all the styling, not Tiny MCE. The person posting an article in the Joomla backend should **not be able to modify the inline css**. Nor should the inline css remain when something is copy-pasted.

Unless they toggle the editor to the html view. Where people would be able to write inline css.

**Is it possible to realise this with Tiny MCE? If not what is another solution?**

**EDIT: I pretty much figured it out with modifying settings in extended mode and "paste as text" in the edit menu. All that is left is to set "paste as text" as default behavior.**

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

- Go to Extensions > Plugins, search for and open the Editor - TimyMCE plugin
- Set Use Joomla Text Filtering to Yes, and save
- Go to System > Global Configuration > Text Filters
- Change the Filter Type and Filter Attribute settings for the User Group you are concerned about. The important bits are that you want to include standard filtering for security reasons, and in your specific case, also filter out the style attribute

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: This does block the style attribute as intended. But it also blocks the style attribute if it is inserted in the html-mode. I do want people to be able to insert the style attribute in the html-mode (in case they know their html-stuff).

Comment: Still +1 for directing me in the right direction. I pretty much figured it out with modifying settings in extended mode and paste as text in the edit menu. All that is left is to set paste as text on as default.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @RMo, I'm pleased you have it solved